# Writing a function to print a string stored in an array

Tags: c, arrays, function

im writing a program that stores user-input strings in an array. Then i pass the array into a function to print the second element. However i realise the program crashes whenever the print inside the function is executed.

My sample code below:

```
main()
{
int num, count;
char strStorage[10][10];

printf("\nEnter how many strings: ");
scanf( "%d" , &num);
fflush(stdin);

for ( count = 0 ; count < num ; count++)
{
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(strStorage[count]);
    fflush(stdin);
}

//This works
printf("%s", strStorage[2]);

printMyArray(strStorage);
}

void printMyArray(char *myArray[ ])
{
    //This doesnt work
    printf("%s", myArray[2]);

}
```

Im doing this in order to learn how arrays get passed to functions. Appreciate it if anyone can help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error-messages? What environment are you using? GCC, Visual Studio? Also consider, that you are using fixed-size-arrays. If you put more than 9 characters (don't forget about trailing '\0', you will overwrite the inner bounds inside the array). In C you don't pass arrays, but actually pointers or addresses of your variables.

Comment: The program crashes as in i get the Windows Error reporting thingy.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should really pass your double array as a double array, and not as an array of pointers.

```
 void printMyArray(char *myArray[ ])
```

becomes

```
 void printMyArray(char myArray[][10])
```

Comment: Did try it and it did not work. As far as i know when i call 
printMyArray(strStorage); what is being passed over is the address, not the entire array. 

So at the function, the arguments (or parameters) must be stored as a pointer as what is really being passed is an address, not an array.

I may be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems with your code:

A) You set aside space for 10 strings, but the user can choose to input more than 10, and you do nothing to stop them.

B) The user can input a string longer than 9 characters (the max you set).

C) As other answers will say `char* []` is not the same as `char [][10]`

Comment: Yes the 10 strings thingy is just for a test the function temporarily. I just wanted to get the array passing right.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

`char *myArray[ ]` declares an array of pointers. So, each element is a double pointer.

To access the elements you need to

```
printf("%s", *myArray[2]);
```

Here, `*myArray[2]` is equivalent to `*(*(myArray + 2))` where `*(myArray + 2)` points to the second pointer in the array of pointers, and adding another `*` accesses the value pointed to by that pointer.

Comment: I have tried that before and it did not work. I guess the problem is with the array being passes over.

Thanks for the input though